# Proper way of merging a feature branch into another feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge

Recently I faced the following issue:

Say I have three branches - **master, branch_feature1, branch_feature2**. Lets assume that the two features are being developed by different people (developer 1 and developer 2). Developer 2 realizes that he will be needing parts of feature 1 for feature 2. So, he pulls branch_feature1 into branch_feature2.

Now, he makes some changes in feature2 which change some files of feature 1 (lets refer to these changes as common_changes). Now, **branch_feature2** gets merged into **master**. Now when developer 1 takes a pull from master (to rebase his work to the latest master), some files have changed in his work (git won't give a conflict since developer 2 made those 'common_changes' on top of **branch_feature1** commits). This is a major issue since developer 1 doesn't know about 'common_changes' which were made on top of his commits by some other developer.

**Edit: Here's a very simplified example of my issue:**

Say **branch_feature1** has two commits on top of **master**:

commit 1 which changes the file **feature1_constants.h**:

```
int feature1_constant = 10;
```

commit 2 which changes the file **common_constants.h**:

```
int common_constant = 100;   // say that in master branch this value was 10 and was changed to 100 in commit 2
```

Now developer 2 pulls branch_feature1 into his branch; so that commit 1 and commit 2 will be a part of **branch_feature2** as well. Developer 2 makes a commit (say commit 3) which changes common_constants.h and adds some more files for his own feature (feature 2):

```
int common_constant = 10; // changed from 100 (from commit 2) to 10
```

Now, commit 3 is on top of commit 2. So when branch_feature2 gets merged into master and then gets pulled by developer 1, git won't report a conflict for common_constants.h since commit 3 is on top of commit 2.

So, whats the correct way of incorporating parts of feature 1 into feature 2? If I simply do a git merge, there is a chance that some files of feature 1 can be changed by some other developer on the top of my commit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: better if you take the time to create a small text-based diagram and state a clear question - it's hard to tell what your question is

Comment: I would say, that feature1 should have been splitted to a common part, which can be merged earlier and then be used by feature2.
Taking an open feature branch can be critical, as before the final merge, rebase, refactor, ... are common to do the final fixes (e.g. linting).

Comment: @arch What if feature 1 was being developed before feature 2? It won't be feasible to split feature 1 branch into a common part right?

Comment: It depends on the commit history of feature 1. But if the common part can be extracted from a bunch of commit, a quick (interactive) rebase should be able to move these commits to the beginning of the feature branch. Then checkout the final commit of the common part. Create a new branch and merge it. Afterwards, rebase feature1 to the merged branch.

In case feature1 does not break anything, it may also be make ready for a merge and then fully developed.

Comment: @AlexanderMills added a simplified example to elaborate. Hope that clarifies the question

Comment: I think that whoever worked on `feature2` messed up. Given that the developer _depends_ on work that is being developed independently and, **most importantly**, it could change dramatically (or **rebased**), `developer2` **has to** wait for work from `feature1`  to finally be merged so that they then can ask to merge **their** stuff. Does that mean that the developer has to wait for `feature1` to be finished to start working? **Nope**. It's fine to pull other stuff into your branch.... but you need to be careful to **clean it up** from the branch once you will make the request to merge it....

Comment: That is why it is recommended to keep all the changes related to a feature as a single block of linear commits that you can rebase easily.... if you start doing merges here and there in the history of your branch, it will be painful.... still possible, but painful.

Comment: The question is still vague. The answer to “incorporating parts” is to use `git cherry-pick`. But then if you put that into practice you’ll end up in a rats nest of complicated situations. Then you (general you) come back and ask why after you picked A, B, D, but not C and E you get a conflict after `feature3` was merged to `main` which used cherry-picked A and E from `feature1`. And then people have to take 10 minutes to understand what even happened. Is this viable?